# How to create wordcloud showing most common bigrams in a text using Python?

Tags: python, textblob

I am trying to analyze twitter data using textblob. Most commonly used Bigrams of my twitter text and their respective frequencies are retrieved and stored in a list variable 'l' as shown below.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
blob = TextBlob(text)

import nltk, re, string, collections
from nltk.util import ngrams

'first get individual words'
tokenized = blob.split()

'and get a list of all the bi-grams'
Bigrams = ngrams(tokenized, 2)
Bigrams

'get the frequency of each bigram '
BigramFreq = collections.Counter(Bigrams)
BigramFreq

' what are the ten most popular bigrams '
l = BigramFreq.most_common(10)
l
```

Here the output of 'l' is a list containg bigrams and frequencies of each bigram shown as below after running the above code:

```
  [(('@UniverCurious:', 'The'), 39),
 (('The', 'underside'), 38),
 (('underside', 'of'), 38),
 (('of', 'Jupiter.'), 38),
 (('Jupiter.', 'Credit:'), 38),
 (('Credit:', 'NASA/JPL/JUNO'), 38),
 (('to', 'the'), 25),
 (('just', '100'), 15),
 (('20', 'years'), 14)]
```

Now I am able to create a table from the most common bigrams. But i need help with creation of wordcloud from the given code above.

My question is how to create a  wordcloud from this list 'l'?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: a =  [(('@UniverCurious:', 'The'), 39),
   ...:  (('The', 'underside'), 38),
   ...:  (('underside', 'of'), 38),
   ...:  (('of', 'Jupiter.'), 38),
   ...:  (('Jupiter.', 'Credit:'), 38),
   ...:  (('Credit:', 'NASA/JPL/JUNO'), 38),
   ...:  (('to', 'the'), 25),
   ...:  (('just', '100'), 15),
   ...:  (('20', 'years'), 14)]

In [3]: ngram_list = [" ".join(p[0]) for p in a]

In [4]: cnt_list = [p[1] for p in a]

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ngram_list, cnt_list)), columns=['bigram', 'cnt'])

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
                  bigram  cnt
0    @UniverCurious: The   39
1          The underside   38
2           underside of   38
3            of Jupiter.   38
4       Jupiter. Credit:   38
5  Credit: NASA/JPL/JUNO   38
6                 to the   25
7               just 100   15
8               20 years   14
```

How about this? And for wordcloud, you may need to use other modules like `wordcloud`. See [this link](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/wordcloud-python) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Table creation works fine now.
Now i extended my code for creation of a wordcloud but it gives an error "TypeError: expected string". The code i extended is as shown below:

```
 'converting the list 'words' into a dictionary 'dict'. Dictionary is 
  to be used for creation of wordcloud.'

  d = {}
  for  ngram_list,cnt_list in l:
       d[ngram_list]= cnt_list
    
  d  

   from wordcloud import WordCloud
  'generate a word cloud from a dictionary of frequencies'
   wordcloud = WordCloud(colormap='prism').generate_from_frequencies(d)
   wordcloud.to_image()
```

The error is as shown below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-9de1b9f89116> in <module>
     17 
     18 # generate a word cloud from a dictionary of frequencies
---> 19 wordcloud = WordCloud(colormap = 'prism').generate_from_frequencies(d)
     20 wordcloud.to_image()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py in generate_from_frequencies(self, frequencies, max_font_size)
    432             else:
    433                 self.generate_from_frequencies(dict(frequencies[:2]),
--> 434                                                max_font_size=self.height)
    435                 # find font sizes
    436                 sizes = [x[1] for x in self.layout_]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py in generate_from_frequencies(self, frequencies, max_font_size)
    486                     font, orientation=orientation)
    487                 # get size of resulting text
--> 488                 box_size = draw.textsize(word, font=transposed_font)
    489                 # find possible places using integral image:
    490                 result = occupancy.sample_position(box_size[1] + self.margin,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py in textsize(self, text, font, spacing, direction, features, language)
    337         if font is None:
    338             font = self.getfont()
--> 339         return font.getsize(text, direction, features, language)
    340 
    341     def multiline_textsize(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py in getsize(self, text, *args, **kwargs)
    489 
    490     def getsize(self, text, *args, **kwargs):
--> 491         w, h = self.font.getsize(text)
    492         if self.orientation in (Image.ROTATE_90, Image.ROTATE_270):
    493             return h, w

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py in getsize(self, text, direction, features, language)
    221         :return: (width, height)
    222         """
--> 223         size, offset = self.font.getsize(text, direction, features, language)
    224         return (size[0] + offset[0], size[1] + offset[1])
    225 

TypeError: expected string
```

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong here.